Как подключить OpenGL32 в Visual Studio?
Использую Visual Studio.
Открываю это:
https://github.com/4DA/Unigine-legacy/blob/master/
Открываю в Visual Studio Engine.sln https://github.com/4DA/Unigine-legacy/tree/master/win32
Ошибка #include <GL/glext.h> .
Ошибка (активно)    E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "GL/glext.h"   Engine  D:\Unigine-legacy-master\engine.h   36
Нужна OpenGL32.lib
У меня уже есть OpenGL32.lib
c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\libopengl32.a
c:\msys64\ucrt64\lib\libopengl32.a
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\OpenGL32.Lib
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86\OpenGL32.Lib
c:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll
c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-opengl_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_6ab9e7b9a318b3e8\opengl32.dll
c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-opengl_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23403_none_6d7e3692b91ddaf8\opengl32.dll
c:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-opengl_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_0e9b4c35eabb42b2\opengl32.dll
c:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-opengl_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23403_none_115f9b0f00c069c2\opengl32.dll

Как подключить OpenGL32.lib в Visual Studio?

Проверьте чтобы у вас было установлено окружение для работы с си/с++ https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/api/GL/glext.h

Ну а вообще сдк от Майкрософт, не поставляется с расширениями для gl. Glad, sdl, glfw, в помощь.

Прежде, чем браться за этот проект, вам необходимо рекурсивно разобраться со всеми его зависимостями, к которым относится glext.h.
